# Evaluating both column name and the target value within `j` expression within `data.table`

Tags: r, data.table

Consider

```
target <- "vs"
value <- 1

library(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(head(mtcars))
```

So I'm trying to pass both column name and a value as variables into the `j` expression within `data.table` environment, something that would be equivalent to

```
dt[, vs == 1]
# [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

If only the value is the variable, it works nicely

```
dt[, vs == value]
# [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

We can also call the column within the data.table scope when it's a variable

```
dt[, target, with = FALSE]
#    vs
# 1:  0
# 2:  0
# 3:  1
# 4:  1
# 5:  0
# 6:  1
```

**But I can't figure how to combine the two in a simple manner**

*Note:* I'm well aware that I can simply do:

```
dt[[target]] == value
# [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

But I need it within the data table scope so I could modify other columns by reference, something like

```
dt[, NEWCOL := sum(vs == 1), by = am]
```

So here are my tries when both column name and the value are variables

```
dt[, target == value, with = FALSE]
# Null data.table (0 rows and 0 cols)
dt[, target == value]
# [1] FALSE
dt[, (target) == value]
# [1] FALSE
dt[, .(target == value)]
# V1
# 1: FALSE
dt[, eval(target) == value]
# [1] FALSE
dt[target %in% value]
## Empty data.table (0 rows) of 11 cols: mpg,cyl,disp,hp,drat,wt...
```

Eventually I came up with

```
dt[, .SD[[target]] == value]
# [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

but it is very inefficient, here's a simple benchmark

```
set.seed(123)
n <- 1e6
dt <- data.table(vs = sample(1L:30L, n, replace = TRUE), am = seq_len(n))
system.time(dt[, NEWCOL := sum(.SD[[target]] == value), by = am])
#  user  system elapsed 
# 13.00    0.02   13.12 
system.time(dt[, NEWCOL2 := sum(vs == value), by = am])
# user  system elapsed 
# 0.82    0.00    0.83
```

**Question**: Is there any better way of doing this that I'm missing here? Something either more idiomatic or much more efficient

---

**Edit**

Originally I was looking for something idiomatic, so I thought  @GGrothendieck simple solution using `get` was the one, but surprisingly all @Richard version are beating even the version that *ins't* doing any evaluation of the column name

```
set.seed(123)
n <- 1e7
dt <- data.table(vs = sample(1L:30L, n, replace = TRUE), am = seq_len(n))

cl <- substitute(
  x == y, 
  list(x = as.name(target), y = value)
)
cl2 <- call("==", as.name(target), value)

system.time(dt[, NEWCOL := sum(vs == value), by = am])
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.83    0.00    0.82 
system.time(dt[, NEWCOL1 := sum(.SD[[target]] == value), by = am])
#   user  system elapsed 
#   8.97    0.00    8.97 
system.time(dt[, NEWCOL2 := sum(get(target) == value), by = am])
#   user  system elapsed 
#   2.35    0.00    2.37 
system.time(dt[, NEWCOL3 := sum(eval(cl)), by = am])
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.69    0.02    0.71 
system.time(dt[, NEWCOL4 := sum(eval(cl2)), by = am])
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.76    0.00    0.77 
system.time(dt[, NEWCOL5 := sum(eval(as.name(target)) == value), by = am])
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.78    0.00    0.78
```

Comment: These all look really strange to me. (@jangorecki's bounty brought me here.) Why use `by` with a row counter? That can't possibly be optimal. And why `sum` a 0/1 scalar? The same vector can be produced 700x faster (on my computer) with `dt[,mycol:=0L];dt[get(target)==value,mycol:=1L]`. Check with `dt[,table(mycol,NEWCOL5)]`

Comment: Besides I've learn interesting substitution from Richard's answer I still cannot deal with similar *programming update by reference* on character vector input. Something like: a) `select <- c("value"); DT[JN, c("value") := list(i.value)]` and b) `select <- c("value","meta"); DT[JN, c("value","meta") := list(i.value,i.meta)`. Tried with `lapply(select, as.name(paste0("i.",select)))` but `name`s nested in list seems to not be catched. I may start a new question for that.

Comment: [here it is](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30468455/dynamically-build-call-for-lookup-multiple-columns).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is one possible alternative.

```
target <- "vs"
value <- 1
dt <- as.data.table(head(mtcars))
```

In terms of code it's not necessarily simpler, but we can set up an unevaluated call `cl` defined outside the scope of `dt` which is to be evaluated inside the data table's environment.

```
cl <- substitute(
    x == y, 
    list(x = as.name(target), y = value)
)
```

`substitute()` might be necessary for longer expressions.  But in this case, `call()` would shorten the code and create the same `cl` result.  And so `cl` could also be

```
cl <- call("==", as.name(target), value)
```

Now we can evaluate `cl` inside `dt`.  On your example this seems to work fine.

```
dt[, NEWCOL := sum(eval(cl)), by = am][]
#     mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb NEWCOL
# 1: 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4      1
# 2: 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4      1
# 3: 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1      1
# 4: 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1      2
# 5: 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2      2
# 6: 18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1      2
```

After thinking about this for a minute, I'm not sure `value` needed to be substituted, and hence the following also works.  But as David notes, the first approach is more time efficient.

```
dt[, eval(as.name(target)) == value]
# [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: I found this answer very valuable, just for preparing calls for flexible usage of `data.table`. Unfortunately I need to wait 23h before I can give you a bounty. BTW. Similar approach instead of `j` arg in `i` argument: [gist](https://gist.github.com/jangorecki/06a05f0efab256765f53).

Comment: Can you check last comment under the question? maybe it would be simple for you...