# data.table subsetting by variable containing a column name

Tags: r, data.table, subset

I have a data table whose column names are not known in advance

```
set.seed(1)
titles <- rep(letters[sample.int(3,replace = T)],2)
dt <- data.table( x = c(1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1), y = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2) )
dt = dcast(dt, x+y ~ titles, fill=0, value.var = 'x')
> dt
   x y a b
1: 1 1 1 0
2: 1 2 1 2
3: 3 1 0 2
```

I wish to remove rows whose last column is 0, but 'subset' doesn't work. Why?

```
dt <- subset( dt, last(titles) > 0 )
```

I'd preferrably use data.table methods.

Comment: We can try `dt[b!=0]`

Comment: @akrun he doesn't know it's `b`. I guess one way is `dt[dt[[last(titles)]] > 0]`, but it's a good question on what's the idiomatic way to do this.

Comment: Then `dt[get(tail(names(dt),1))!=0]` or `dt[get(tail(titles,1))!=0]`

Comment: Or `dt[eval(as.name(last(titles))) > 0]`

Comment: I would guess [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27677283/evaluating-both-column-name-and-the-target-value-within-j-expression-within-d) somewhat related

Comment: The link David Arenburg directs to, suggest also dt[,.SD[[last(titles)]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `get`

```
 dt[get(last(titles))!=0]
```