# R Datatable - slow access to value.labels attribute using string as name of variable

Tags: r, data.table, attr

When working with data imported from SPSS I need to access value.labels attribute of some variables.

The names of these variables I get as strings. The only way to pass the variable name (as string) to attr which I have found is through get() but it is very very slow.
The situation is quite simple so there is probably a better way how to do it.

The example is artificial but the size (number of variables) is similar to what I work with in real. I also need the data.table in the real situation.

```
library(data.table)

id <- c(1:4000) 
x <- sample(1:3, 4000, replace=T)
dv<-c(id,x)
df<-data.frame(t(dv))
dt<-data.table(df)

attr(dt$X1,"value.labels")<-c("first","second","third")


#direct approach is fast
pm<-proc.time()
attr(dt[,X1],"value.labels")
proc.time() - pm

   user  system elapsed 
   0.00    0.04    0.03 

#using variable name as a string is slow
pm<-proc.time()
attr(dt[,get("X1")],"value.labels")
proc.time() - pm

   user  system elapsed 
   0.85    0.03    0.89
```

The get() solution is incredibly slow but it works.

```
attr(dt[,"X1", with=FALSE],"value.labels")
NULL

attr(dt[,match("X1",names(dt)),with=FALSE],"value.labels")
NULL
```

Does not work.

Comment: Try `attr(dt[,eval(as.name("X1"))],"value.labels")`. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27677283/evaluating-both-column-name-and-the-target-value-within-j-expression-within-d). Try also `attr(dt[["X1"]],"value.labels")`

Comment: Very fast and works well, thank you.

Comment: @DavidArenburg you could post this as answer

Comment: @jangorecki I was afraid it's a dupe of my question, what do you think?

Comment: @DavidArenburg don't know, it wouldn't hurt anyway

Comment: @jangorecki I mean, should I just hammer it as there is a already a good answer?

Comment: @DavidArenburg it answers the question so yeah