# R data.table: accessing column with variable name

Tags: r, data.table

I am using the wonderful R data.table package. However, accessing (i.e. manipulating by reference) a column with a variable name is very clumsy: If we are given a data.table `dt` which has two columns x and y and we want to add two columns and name it z then the command is

```
dt = dt[, z := x + y]
```

Now let us write a function `add` that takes as arguments a (reference to a) data.table `dt` and three column names `summand1Name`, `summand2Name` and `resultName` and it is supossed to execute the exact same command as above only with general column names. The solution I am using right now is reflection, i.e.

```
add = function(dt, summand1Name, summand2Name, resultName) {
  cmd = paste0('dt = dt[, ', resultName, ' := ', summand1Name, ' + ', summand2Name, ']')
  eval(parse(text=cmd))
  return(dt) # optional since manipulated  by reference
}
```

However I am absolutely not satisfied with this solution. First of all it's clumsy, it does not make fun to code like this. It is hard to debug and it just pisses me off and burns time. Secondly, it is harder to read and understand. Here is my question:

***Can we write this function in a somewhat nicer way?***

I am aware of the fact that one can access columns with variable name like so: `dt[[resultName]]` but when I write

```
dt[[resultName]] = dt[[summand1Name]] + dt[[summand2Name]]
```

then data.table starts to complain about having taken copies and not working by reference. I don't want that. Also I like the syntax `dt = dt[<all 'database related operations'>]` so that everything I am doing is stuck together in one pair of brackets. Isn't it possible to make use of a special symbol like backticks or so in order to indicate that the name currently used is not referencing an actual column of the data table but rather is a placeholder for the name of an actual column?

Comment: You should probably look at `get` and `mget`

Comment: See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27677283/evaluating-both-column-name-and-the-target-value-within-j-expression-within-d)

Comment: How about `add = function(dt, summand1Name, summand2Name, resultName) dt[, (resultName) := .SD[[summand1Name]] + .SD[[summand2Name]]]`? Another option could be `add2 = function(dt, summand1Name, summand2Name, resultName) dt[, (resultName) := eval(as.name(summand1Name)) + eval(as.name(summand2Name))]` or just use `get` as suggested above.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine the use of `()` on the LHS of `:=` as well as `with = FALSE` in referencing a variable on the RHS.

```
dt <- data.table(a = 1:5, b = 10:14)
my_add <- function(dt, summand1Name, summand2Name, resultName) {
  dt[, (resultName) := dt[, summand1Name, with = FALSE] + 
       dt[, summand1Name, with = FALSE]]
}
my_add(dt, 'a', 'b', 'c')
dt
```

**Edit:**

Compared three versions. Mine is the most inefficient... (but will keep it just for reference).

```
set.seed(1)
dt <- data.table(a = rnorm(10000), b = rnorm(10000))
original_add <- function(dt, summand1Name, summand2Name, resultName) {
  cmd = paste0('dt = dt[, ', resultName, ' := ', summand1Name, ' + ', summand2Name, ']')
  eval(parse(text=cmd))
  return(dt) # optional since manipulated  by reference
}
my_add <- function(dt, summand1Name, summand2Name, resultName) {
  dt[, (resultName) := dt[, summand1Name, with = FALSE] + 
       dt[, summand1Name, with = FALSE]]
}
list_access_add <- function(dt, summand1Name, summand2Name, resultName) {
  dt[, (resultName) := dt[[summand1Name]] + dt[[summand2Name]]]
}
david_add <- function(dt, summand1Name, summand2Name, resultName) {
  dt[, (resultName) := .SD[[summand1Name]] + .SD[[summand2Name]]]
}

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  original_add(dt, 'a', 'b', 'c'),
  my_add(dt, 'a', 'b', 'c'),
  list_access_add(dt, 'a', 'b', 'c'),
  david_add(dt, 'a', 'b', 'c'))

## Unit: microseconds
##                                expr      min        lq      mean    median        uq      max
##     original_add(dt, "a", "b", "c")  604.397  659.6395  784.2206  713.0315  776.1295 5070.541
##           my_add(dt, "a", "b", "c") 1063.984 1168.6140 1460.5329 1247.7990 1486.9730 6134.959
##  list_access_add(dt, "a", "b", "c")  272.822  310.9680  422.6424  334.3110  380.6885 3620.463
##        david_add(dt, "a", "b", "c")  389.389  431.9080  542.7955  454.5335  493.4895 3696.992
##  neval
##    100
##    100
##    100
##    100
```

**Edit2:**

With one million rows, the result looks like this. As expected the original method perform well as once `eval` is done this will work fast.

```
## Unit: milliseconds
##                                expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq      max
##     original_add(dt, "a", "b", "c")  2.493553  3.499039  6.585651  3.607101  4.390051 114.0612
##           my_add(dt, "a", "b", "c") 11.821820 14.512878 28.387841 17.412433 19.642231 117.6359
##  list_access_add(dt, "a", "b", "c")  2.161276  3.133110  6.874885  3.218185  3.407776 107.6853
##        david_add(dt, "a", "b", "c")  2.237089  3.313133  6.047832  3.381757  3.788558 103.7532
##  neval
##    100
##    100
##    100
##    100
```

Comment: You could also use `substitute` and `eval`, or potential Hadley's nicer `quo` and `UQ` functions from `rlang` or the dev version of `dplyr` to do the without recalling `dt` which doesn't seem ideal

Comment: I.e `summand1 = substitute (summand1Name)...` inside the function at the start and later `dt[, (resultName) := eval(summand1) + eval(summand2)]`. Here you pass in the bare column names, rather than strings for the summands.

Comment: First of all `with = FALSE` also takes copies, seconds of all `dt[[summand1Name]]` will be way more efficient than `dt[, summand1Name, with = FALSE]`.

Comment: @David_Arenburg. Yes, you're quite right. See my edits.

Comment: The different approaches behave quite different when using by-group operations - you don't want to use some of them in such scenarios. Compare `dt[, sum(dt[["a"]]), by = cut(b, breaks = c(-Inf, 0, Inf))];dt[, sum(a), by = cut(b, breaks = c(-Inf, 0, Inf))];dt[, sum(.SD[["a"]]), by = cut(b, breaks = c(-Inf, 0, Inf))]; dt[, sum(dt[, "a", with = FALSE]), by = cut(b, breaks = c(-Inf, 0, Inf))]`

Comment: Did with a data will 1M rows.

Answer (score 1):

```r
new_add <- function(dt, summand1Name, summand2Name, resultName) {
    dt[, (resultName) := rowSums(.SD), .SDcols = c(summand1Name, summand2Name)]
}
```

This just takes the column names as strings.
Adding this to amatsuo_net's speed test, and adding sindri's two versions too, we get the following:

```r
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  original_add(dt, 'a', 'b', 'c'),
  my_add(dt, 'a', 'b', 'c'),
  list_access_add(dt, 'a', 'b', 'c'),
  david_add(dt, 'a', 'b', 'c'),
  new_add(dt, 'a', 'b', 'c'),
  get_add(dt, 'a', 'b', 'c'),
  mget_add(dt, 'a', 'b', 'c'))

## Unit: microseconds
##                               expr   min      lq     mean median      uq     max neval
##    original_add(dt, "a", "b", "c") 433.3  491.00  635.315  531.4  600.00  6064.0   100
##          my_add(dt, "a", "b", "c") 978.0 1062.35 1310.808 1208.8 1357.80  4157.3   100
## list_access_add(dt, "a", "b", "c") 303.9  331.95  432.939  363.8  434.05  3361.6   100
##       david_add(dt, "a", "b", "c") 401.3  440.65  659.748  474.5  577.75 11623.0   100
##         new_add(dt, "a", "b", "c") 518.9  588.30  765.394  667.1  741.95  5636.5   100
##         get_add(dt, "a", "b", "c") 415.1  454.50  674.699  491.1  546.70  9804.3   100
##        mget_add(dt, "a", "b", "c") 425.4  474.65  596.165  533.2  590.75  3888.0   100
```

It's not the fastest among the versions, but if you're looking for code that's painless to write then this is pretty simple. Since it works off of `rowSums`, it can also more easily be generalised to sum over an arbitrary number of columns at once.

Additionally, since `dt` isn't mentioned inside the square brackets, you can add this column definition inside a data.table "pipe" instead of as a function, if you want to:

```r
dt[, (resultName) := rowSums(.SD), .SDcols = c(summand1Name, summand2Name)
][, lapply(.SD, range), .SDcols = c(summand1Name, summand2Name, resultName)
][... # etc
]
```

Comment: I've added sindri's versions to the benchmark.

Comment: Thank you. Interesting results.

Answer (score 1):

Using `get()`:

```r
add <- function(dt, summand1Name, summand2Name, resultName) {
  dt[, (resultName) := get(summand1Name) + get(summand1Name)]
}
```

Using `mget()`:

```
add2 <- function(dt, summand1Name, summand2Name, resultName) {
  dt[, (resultName) := do.call(`+`, mget(c(summand1Name,summand2Name)))]
}
```

```
# Let
dt <- data.table(a = 1:5, b = 10:14)
# Then
add(dt, 'x', 'y', 'z')
dt[]
#    x y z
# 1: 1 2 2
```

Comment: `+` can only take 1 or 2 arguments, so the mget version would need a little tweaking to scale to more columns.

Comment: @AccidentalStatistician Oh, thank you. One could use Reduce() instead of do.call() but I guess rowSums() would be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution using `substitute`. I generally try to avoid using `substitute`, but I think it's the only way of using fast `data.table` and `:=` code instead of native list access.

I kept to the interface of amatsuo_net.

```
set.seed(1)
dt <- data.table(a = rnorm(10000), b = rnorm(10000))

snaut_add <- function(dt, summand1, summand2, resultName){
  eval(substitute(
    dt[, z := x + y],
    list(
      z=as.symbol(resultName),
      x=as.symbol(summand1),
      y=as.symbol(summand2)
    )
  ))
}

snaut_add(dt, "a", "b", "c")
dt
```