# data.table grouped operations with variable names of columns without slow DT[, mean(get(colName)), by = grp]

Tags: r, data.table

I want to create a function which uses variable names of columns and variable name of data.

This function is what I want and it works :

```
n <- 1e7
d <- data.table(x = 1:n, grp = sample(1:1e5, n, replace = T))
dataName = "d"
colName = "x"

# Objective :
FOO <- function(dataName = "d",
         colName = "x"){
  get(dataName)[, mean(get(colName)), by = grp]
}
```

The problem is that evaluation of `get()` for each group is very time-consuming. On a real data example it is 14 times longer than the static-name equivalent. I would like to reach the same execution time as if the column names were static.

What I tried :

```
(cl <- substitute(mean(eval(parse(text = colName))), list(colName = as.name(colName))))

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(

  # 1) works and quick but does not use variable names of columns (654ms)
  (t1 <- d[, mean(x), by = grp]),

  # 2) works but slow (1006ms)
  (t2 <- get(dataName)[, mean(get(colName)), by = grp]), # works but slow

  # 3) works but slow (4075ms)
  (t3 <- eval(parse(text = dataName))[, mean(eval(parse(text = colName))), by = grp]),

  # 4) works but very slow (37202ms)
  (t4 <- get(dataName)[, eval(cl), by = grp]),

  # 5) double dot syntax doesn't work cause I don't master it
  # (t5 <- get(dataName)[, mean(..colName), by = grp]),

  times = 10)
```

Is the double dot syntax appropriate here ? Why is 4) so slow ? I took it from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27677283/evaluating-both-column-name-and-the-target-value-within-j-expression-within-d) where it was the best option. I adapted the double dot syntax from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12392269/13175203).

Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: Is there a particular reason your `FOO` function needs to get the data from a variable *name* using `get`? That method will be horribly difficult to troubleshoot based on namespace/environment inheritance (esp if in nested function calls), and seems unnecessarily inefficient (instead of `FOO("mydata")`, just call `FOO(mydata)`?).

Comment: Thanks ! I thought that passing the data to the function would copy it and would be less efficicent but it seems to be a misconception. I should learn more about the mechanics of R functions. Thanks for pointing out those drawbacks :)

Comment: Use env var to parameterize your data.table query, note that this feature may not be yet on CRAN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be better to pass the dataset name `d` to the `FOO` function instead of passing the character string `"d"`. Also, you can use `lapply` combined with `.SD` so that you can benefit from internal optimization instead of using `mean(get(colName))`.

```
FOO2 = function(dataName=d, colName = "x") { # d instead of "d" passed to the first argument!
  dataName[, lapply(.SD, mean), by=grp, .SDcols=colName]
}
```

#### Benchmark: `FOO` vs `FOO2`

```
set.seed(147852)
n <- 1e7
d <- data.table(x = 1:n, grp = sample(1:1e5, n, replace = T))

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  FOO(),
  FOO2(),
  times=5L
)

Unit: milliseconds
   expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
  FOO() 4632.4014 4672.7781 4787.4958 4707.9023 4846.7081 5077.6893     5
 FOO2()  255.0828  267.1322  297.0389  275.4467  281.9873  405.5456     5
```

Comment: Thank you very much Christian ! It works very well ! In my real-life example, I am doing several operations at once with several columns such as `colName` : `.N`, `sum(colName1)`, `sum(colName2 * colName3)`... so I put all the needed columns in `.SDcols` and referred to each by `.SD[,1]`, `.SD[,2]`